# How many Product Keys do I need for Windows 8? one or more?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, product-key

I came to know that many people buying more than one product key for Windows 8. What's the use of getting more Keys? Suppose If I purchase only one product key, OS available for limited time or Life time?

Comment: You need one key per pc you own.

Comment: If you want the media center pack add on, you will need a key for that, [get one for free here-limited time offer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs)

Comment: They might be buying more that one because Microsoft is discounting the price for a while, some may be stocking up while it is cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS is available for a lifetime. If you are a normal user then 1 key per computer you own will be enough for daily use. But for IT departments they require more than 1 as they have to install Windows 8 for the corporation. (Meaning at least 100 computers need their own key)

If you want the Media Center pack add on for Windows 8 Pro, you will need a key for that, [get one for free here-limited time offer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs)

Comment: If you have 100 computers, volume licensing (VLK/MAK/KMS) is the way to go, not individual retail version keys.